# Is +load method guaranteed to be called after system update/device reboot?

Tags: ios

I was writing a small utility class to get the iOS version that my app is running on. I thought that since iOS version won't change while my app is running, it's OK to read the version once, cache it and then return a cached value (since it requires a string splitting, operations with an array, etc.). And a good place to do it might be a `+load` method of my utility class: it will only be called once, I don't need any additional `if`s in my getters. This is what I came up with:

Utils.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Utils : NSObject

/**
 *  Returnes a major part of the iOS version that runs on the current device.
 *  I.e. returns 8 for iOS 8.1.2
 */
+(int)iOSMajorVersion;

/**
 *  Returns a minor part of the iOS version that runs on the current device.
 *  I.e. returns 1 for iOS 8.1.2 or 0 for iOS 7.0.1.
 */
+(int)iOSMinorVersion;

@end
```

Utils.m:

```
#import "Utils.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@implementation Utils

static int minorVersion = -1;
static int majorVersion = -1;

+(void)readVersions {
    NSArray *versions = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    majorVersion = [versions[0] intValue];
    if (versions.count > 1) {
        minorVersion = [versions[1] intValue];
    }
    else {
        minorVersion = 0;
    }
}

+(void)load {
    [self readVersions];
}

+(int)iOSMajorVersion {
    return majorVersion;
}

+(int)iOSMinorVersion {
    return minorVersion;
}

@end
```

But then I thought: what if user receives an iOS update while my app is running? The device will then be rebooted, **but will `+load` be called again when the app is launched after the update**? I mean, if it was the last app that was running just before the update, is it possible that iOS will `cache` the runtime somehow, and won't reinitialize it again?

From my point of view, the runtime should be reinitialized. It's a different runtime, after all (iOS has been updated), but I was wondering just out of curiosity, if someone knows for sure.

Thanks.

P.S. I know that this "optimization" doesn't worth it (this function won't be used very often in my app), but it is my personal project, so I also use it for educational purposes. Besides, if I write it well once, I can reuse it later, without thinking about questions like this :)

P.P.S. For obvious reasons, I can't run a test to find it out experimentally. Hence, my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the app is removed from memory on the device then the code resources will need to be reloaded and the `+load` method will be called again. The question really is if the app will always be removed from memory when a version change occurs. To date this has been the case as iOS restarts when an update is installed, but that isn't something you should actually rely on. It's possible that in future a security update (for instance) could be released as a quick patch which changes the iOS version but doesn't actually require a system restart or RAM state change.

While unlikely, it's better and safer to cache this kind of information when the app finishes launching or comes to the foreground (depending on what the information is).